# How to get confusion matrix for best_estimator of GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm doing parameter tuning for a `RandomForestClassifier` using `GridSearchCV`. For evaluation purposes I want a confusion matrix for the `best_estimator` which is not saved by `GridSearchCV` as far as I know.

```
gs = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=42), param_grid={'max_depth': range(5, 25, 4), 'min_samples_leaf': range(5, 40, 5),'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini']}, scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_Distances, Y)
results = gs.cv_results_
```

I intialize a gridsearch with the given parameters to receive the `best_parameters`. Eventually I'm using the optimal parameters to replicate the `best_estimator` of gridsearch with a stratified cross validation. I'm assuming that I'm training/validating the `best_estimator` with the same training/test data as gridSearchCV since I'm using the same parameters and cross validation options (stratified + 3 folds).

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, min_samples_leaf=7, max_depth=18, criterion='entropy', random_state=42)
accuracy = []
metrics = {'accuracy':[], 'precision':[], 'recall':[], 'fscore':[], 'support':[]}
counter = 0

print('################################################### RandomForest ###################################################')
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_Distances,Y):
    X_train, X_test = X_Distances[train_index], X_Distances[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

    precision, recall, fscore, support = np.round(score(y_test, y_pred), 2)
    metrics['accuracy'].append(round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 2))
    metrics['precision'].append(precision)
    metrics['recall'].append(recall)
    metrics['fscore'].append(fscore)
    metrics['support'].append(support)

    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    methods.saveConfusionMatrix(matrix, ('confusion_matrix_randomforest_distances_' + str(counter) +'.png'))
    counter = counter+1

meanAcc= round(np.mean(np.asarray(metrics['accuracy'])),2)*100
print('meanAcc: ', meanAcc)
```

I have some concerns regarding overfitting. Is there an easier way to get the confusion matrix for the `best_estimator`? If not, is my approach correct?

EDIT: I just tested the following:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42), param_grid={'max_depth': range(5, 25, 4), 'min_samples_leaf': range(5, 40, 5),'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini']}, scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_Distances, Y)
```

This yields `best_score = 0.5362903225806451` at `best_index = 28`. When I check the accuracies in the 3 folds at index 28 I get:

1. split0: 0.5185929648241207
2. split1: 0.526686807653575
3. split2: 0.5637651821862348

Which leads to the mean test accuracy: 0.5362903225806451. best_params: `{'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 21, 'min_samples_leaf': 5}`

Now I run this code which is using the mentioned best_params with a stratified 3 fold split (like GridSearchCV):

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=5, max_depth=21, criterion='entropy', random_state=42)
accuracy = []
metrics = {'accuracy':[], 'precision':[], 'recall':[], 'fscore':[], 'support':[]}
counter = 0
print('################################################### RandomForest_Gini ###################################################')
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_Distances,Y):
    X_train, X_test = X_Distances[train_index], X_Distances[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

    precision, recall, fscore, support = np.round(score(y_test, y_pred))
    metrics['accuracy'].append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    metrics['precision'].append(precision)
    metrics['recall'].append(recall)
    metrics['fscore'].append(fscore)
    metrics['support'].append(support)

    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    methods.saveConfusionMatrix(matrix, ('confusion_matrix_randomforest_distances_' + str(counter) +'.png'))
    counter = counter+1

meanAcc= np.mean(np.asarray(metrics['accuracy']))
print('meanAcc: ', meanAcc)
```

The metrics dictionairy yields the exact same accuracies (split0: 0.5185929648241207, split1: 0.526686807653575, split2: 0.5637651821862348)

However the mean calculation is a bit off: 0.5363483182213101

Comment: Please clarify & highlight what **exactly** your question is.